# C# Reflection -- Load external DLL's and all dependencies

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, system.reflection

I'm trying to accomplish (what seems to be) an extremely simple dependency injection mechanism for .NET using Reflection.  The goal is to provide an interface to a ServiceFactory class, and use reflection to scope out the available implementors of that interface, and to choose an implementation based on an App.config section.  Sounds simple enough.

The route I've chosen is to use the post-build event of each service implementaion project to copy the implementation .dll into a "ServiceImplementations" folder.  Then, the ServiceFactory class looks in this folder to find available, valid implementors of the interface.  The idea is that, using reflection, I should be able to load this arbitrary DLL and all of its dependencies purely in reflection at runtime.  This is the goal I wish to achieve.

Somewhere along the process, I'm loading these dependencies just fine.  I can check my currently loaded assemblies with
    var asmDomainAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

So I proceed through the Reflection crawl, and I end up loading the dependent assemblies (which in this case are EntityFramework, loaded through NuGet, and System.Web.ApplicationServices, a system file).  Everything is well and good.  Until I reach this line of code:

```
        var serviceImplementationAssembly = CheckLoadedAssemblies(assemblyName);  // This function loads the service implementation assembly and its dependencies
        var appDomainAsm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var implementationTypes = serviceImplementationNamespace.GetTypes();      // Exception here
```

At the last line of code, a ReflectionTypeLoadException is thrown.  This exception contains two LoaderExceptions (each a FileNotFoundException) with the message:

```
         Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

This is very strange.  If I check the asmDomainAsm variable above, I can see that that exact assembly signature *is* loaded in my current AppDomain.  I do not understand why Reflection does not recognize that these are the same assemblies, even though I loaded them at different times.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: As the exception states, it could also very well be one of the assemblies that *EntityFramework* depends on and not the *EntityFramework* assembly itself. You might want to give Fusion Logviewer a try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that you loaded the EntityFramework assembly dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFrom` or `Assembly.LoadFile`?

Comment: @mikez yes, that's exactly what I did.  Is there an issue with that?

Comment: @bitbonk I checked myself, and there are no other dependencies.  EntityFramework is a standalone assembly.  In any case, I have ran Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies on each assembly that I load recursively, so that would not be an issue anyway.

Comment: You still should try Fusion Log Viewer as it can give you more details on any failing assembly binding.

Comment: So I ran Fusion Log Viewer.  When I set the Log Viewer to "Log bind failures to disk", I get three entries in my logger when I run my program.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oyt6q.jpg

Comment: Check out [Suzanne Cooks description of load contexts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx)

Comment: So are you saying that some of my loaded assemblies are in a different Binding Context?  Perhaps because I used Assembly.Load for system assemblies and Assembly.LoadFile for the service implementations?  How would I check this?  They are all in the current AppDomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work.  Essentially, I was trying to handle the AssemblyResolve event manually by loading each assembly, checking its dependencies, and firing off Assembly.Load and Assembly.LoadFile events whenever I please.  When I added a CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve event which, when fired, ran my custom directory searching / assembly loading code, everything just worked.

Due to some internal AppDomain / BundleContext issue, an exception was being thrown.  Switching to AssemblyResolve fixed my issue.  Unfortunately, that's all I know about what happened.  I will accept an answer if anyone can explain what's going on under the covers here.

Comment: That is exactly what I would have suggested. The documentation describes this behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx) with "If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and later an assembly in the load context attempts to load same the assembly by display name, the load attempt fails." but unless you're already aware of the issue it doesn't help much.